# What symbols and signs represent what graphics in Windows Command Line?

Tags: windows, graphics, fonts, cmd

For example, when I input a degree symbol, I get a "block" kind of graphic.
Are there any more symbols that represent something that comes close to graphics, because I'm making an "outline" for my cmd game and I don't want it to be raw text.

Comment: You'll get different output depending on which codepage you're using.

Comment: You'll get different output depending on whether you're using Unicode or raster fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might be a good reference: [Code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).